# What do these two files reactjs and reactDOM do?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-native

Today I'm done with my hello world example with ReactJS,

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
```

Above two CDN's included, Just wants to know, what is the difference between them, why do we need to include them, what is the purpose?

Answer (score 2):

They're meant for detaching the actual logic and processing that React does, from the DOM interaction. [`react-dom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom) is simply used for rendering [`react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react) components into the DOM, finding DOM elements so that React can interact with them. ReactDOM actually only serves us three methods:

- `findDOMNode`, which finds a DOM node from fx. a React ref
- `render` which renders a React component at a specific place in the DOM, and
- `unmountComponentAtNode` which does the opposite of `render` (removes it)